# como resto 2 fechas? y que me retorne la diferencia en dias (php,mysql)

Tags: php, html, mysql

llevo desarrollando un proyecto unos dias y casi termino, pero tengo la idea de borrar las publicaciones que los usuarios hagan, para ello al momento de guardar la publicacion guardo la fecha actual.
tengo pensado sacar la fecha de la base de datos para restarla con la fecha actual y si la diferencia entre esas 2 fechas es 2 dias, quiero borrar la publicacion.
el campo en la base de datos es tipo DATE 1999-12-31
lo que he intentado:

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');
```

$nuevafecha = strtotime ( '-3 day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;
$nuevafecha = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $nuevafecha );

si hace la resta pero lo que quiero es un rwesultado mas concreto de dias para hacer una funcion tipo:
if (fechaResultado == 2){//asumiento que 2 son los dias resultado de la resta
ejecutar el query para borrar el registro.
}

Comment: Puedes utilizar la función `date_diff` de PHP para calcular la diferencia de fechas, pero si lo que quieres es borrar en la DB te recomiendo que lo hagas con un stored procedure o un job, depende del motor de base que estés usando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo resolvi de la siguiente manera

```
$daysActive = 0; //Dias que estara activa la publicacion
$creationDate = "2020-07-13"; //Fecha de publicacion 

$deleteAfter = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date_format(date_create($creationDate), 'Y-m-d')."+$daysActive days"));

$deleteDate = date_create($deleteAfter);
$today = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
$diff = date_diff($deleteDate,$today);
$daysLeft = $diff->format("%R%a");

if($daysLeft >= 0){ //Si supera la fecha se borra.
    echo 'BORRAR';
}else{
    echo 'Esperando hasta el '.$deleteAfter;
}
```

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta es válida, quizá sería una mejor opción para el OP realizar el borrado en la DB utilizando un job o tarea programada (según el motor de base de datos que utilice). Saludos.

Comment: excelente el código, era justo lo que buscaba y no encontraba.me funciono.